# Finding an $i \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $im + k = p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory

1. Let $m,k \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\gcd(m,k) = 1$.
2. Let $\pi$ be a prime positive integer.

**Question:** Does there always exist an $i \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $im + k = p$ s.t. $p$ is a prime positive integer greater than $\pi$?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a consequence of the (highly nontrivial) Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions (which you can google, but which says that there is an infinite number of primes in an arithmetic progression satisfying your conditions, that is, with the difference and first term relatively prime).

Comment: Isn't this equivalent to Dirichlet's result?

Comment: @TimRatigan You mean the OP's question? It is weaker (Dirichlet has  a statement about the density), which is why I say "consequence".

Comment: Yes, OP's.  I always thought Dirichlet had just proven the infinitude of primes of the form $nq+r$ for fixed $q,r$ where $\gcd(q,r)=1$.

Comment: Oh, scratch that, I knew he had proven that the sum of reciprocals of primes of that form was divergent.  I don't know if he had a stronger condition than that.

Comment: @TimRatigan No, he proved that the sum of $1/p$ of this form diverges, while sum of $1/p^s$ of this form is $1/\phi(q) \zeta(s),$ in other words, he found the "analytic density".

Comment: @TimRatigan for a very elegant exposition, check out Serre's "A course in arithmetic".

Comment: The PNT for suitable arithmetic progressions was first proved by de la Vallée-Poussin.